# Validated builds hidden in TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

In the last couple of days, two apps of mine make it to TestFlight and are validated fine. Then, when I fix the "Missing in compliance" warning, the apps are gone. Observe the top two builds of one of the apps in question that display nothing:

[image]

But when I view the build in the Activity tab:

[image]

It says it's validated. Gives me no indication of anything gone wrong. Thoughts? I've used the same application loader and process for weeks (app icon/name intentionally removed).

Comment: I think you can only have 2 builds in testing mode. Try to remove the older ones.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the issue, I have the same problem after expiring all the old builds. I will try to load the app again now that I've expired all the builds.